# Proving intersections of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How would we solve the questions below? I tried part a) but literally got nowhere after 2 lines of working. Help appreciated for either of the two parts.

[image]

Attempt:

let W = {{W1: 1≤1≤m}∩{W2: 1≤2≤m}∩...∩{Wm: 1≤m≤m}}

Since {Wj: 1≤j≤m} is a subspace of V for all 1≤j≤m, the intersections of these sets must be a subspace of V.

Comment: *"Literally got nowhere after 2 lines of working"*: could you be more specific? What exactly was in those two lines?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sure, let me add that in

Comment: The way $W$ is defined in the exercise is not what you wrote down, it should be $W = W_1 \cap W_2 \cap  \dots \cap W_n $ or (without dots) $W = \bigcap_{k = 1}^n W_k$. Make sure that you understand these notations and also in what way the resulting set is different from the one you wrote down. Now, you have to check that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, so you have to use the definition of a subspace and show that $W$ satisfies it. A statement like 'it must be a subspace because something else related to it is a subspace' is not enough.

Comment: Thanks Matthias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guide you through part a); perhaps you can take it from there.

If you want to prove that some subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a *subspace*, you need to show that:

- it is non-empty, e.g. by checking if the zero vector belongs to $W$;
- it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication; e.g. by checking that for arbitrary scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and arbitrary elements $x$ and $y$ from $W$; also $\alpha x + \beta y$ belongs to $W$.

---

Now in your case, $W$ is given to be the *intersection* of $m$ subspaces (labeled $W_k$, $1 \le k \le m$).

- Since every $W_k$ contains the zero vector, the intersection $W$ $\color{red}{(\ldots)}$.
- Take $x,y \in W$ and $\alpha,\beta$ arbitrary:

  - because $x$ and $y$ belong to the intersection $W$, they are in $W_k$ for every $k$; because each of these $W_k$'s is a subspace $\color{red}{(\ldots)}$
  - now since $\alpha x + \beta y \in W_k$ for every $k$, it is also in $\color{red}{(\ldots)}$

Do you understand the reasoning and can you complete the red dots?

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes sense!

Comment: @Programmer Alright; you're welcome!

Comment: Since every Wk contains the zero vector, the intersection W contains the zero vector.

because x and y belong to the intersection W, they are in Wk for every k; because each of these Wk's is a subspace of V.

now since αx+βy∈Wk for every k, it is also in W.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, that's about it. For the middle red dots: because each of the $W_k$'s is a subspace, you have $\alpha x + \beta y \in W_k$ for every $k$.

Comment: @StackTD Does the last exercise allow for us to state that an uncountable(non-empty) intersection is also a linear subspace?